# Find the area that lines inside $r=2a\cos(2x)$ and outside $r=\sqrt 2a$?

Tags: integration

Find the area that lines inside $r=2a\cos(2x)$ and outside $r=\sqrt 2a$?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Can you solve simple ?

Comment: $a  \, \cos(2x)$ or $\arccos(2x)$?

Answer (score 1):

We want the area of the four petal tips outside the circle radius $a\sqrt2$.

The area of half a tip plus $\frac{1}{16}$ the area of the circle is $\int_0^{\pi/8}\frac{1}{2}r^2\ d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/8}2a^2\cos^22\theta\ d\theta=\frac{2+\pi}{8}a^2$. So the area of half a tip is $\frac{a^2}{4}$. Hence the area of the four tips is $2a^2$.

[image]